# Password match tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that I want a tooltip to appear in the textfield when the password does not match with confirm password.

Here is my code for the tooltip. The other is working but the matching of the password doesn't

```
    function validateContact() {
  var valid = true;
  $("#container input[required=true], #container textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('invalid');
    $(this).attr('title','');
    if(!$(this).val()){ 
      $(this).addClass('invalid');
      $(this).attr('title','This field is required');
      valid = false;
    }
    if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !$(this).val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)){
      $(this).addClass('invalid');
      $(this).attr('title','Enter valid email');
      valid = false;
    }  

// for  password match
       if ($("#Password").val() != $("#ConfirmPassword").val()) {     

             $(this).addClass('invalid');
            $(this).attr('title','Password does not Match');
            valid = false;
    }
// end of password match

  }); 
  return valid;
}

  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
    position: {my: "left top", at: "right top"},
    items: "input[required=true], textarea[required=true]",
      content: function() { return $(this).attr( "title" ); }
    });
  });
```

Here is my form code:

```
 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" tabindex=7 name="Password" placeholder="Password" required="true" >

<input type="password" class="form-control" id="ConfirmPassword" tabindex=8 name="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="true">
```

I need some help to solve this.

Comment: if ($("#Password").val() == $("#ConfirmPassword").val()) - shouldn't that be != instead of == ?

Comment: its not working ..i change it. :( the page will load but the data will not be inserted

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?. I mean, there are many possibilities here...

Comment: @Javier yes i try. but none of them worked. i think the problem is in the password match code. any ideas?

Comment: You realized that you check the password field inputs.length times?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a listener inside of a ValidateContract function? Where you call it?

Try putting the listener directly on input, through id... change console.log for tooltip show/message

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#ConfirmPassword', function(){
    if ($("#Password").val() == $(this).val()) 
       console.log("pass are equal");
    else
       console.log("pass are not equal D:")
});
```

Comment: You'll actually need listeners on both `#ConfirmPassword` and on `#Password` -- what if I type my password "blahblahblah" then I confirm it "blahblah "-wait-a-second, I want `x` on the end - continue typing in ConfirmPassword "blahblahblahx", passwords don't match, but go back to Password and add the 'x' on the end; now they match but you won't detect it without a listener on `#Password`.  In any case, I would also check them `.on(change, ...)`

Comment: One thing at a time ... If that code, of question, does not work as expected, I cannot suggest to add more code for other purpose...

Comment: True, I was just thinking out loud I guess.